# How to Iterate over an array of objets using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a javascript file which prints a JSON array of objects:

```json
// myfile.js output
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "blah blah", ... },
  { "id": 2, "name": "xxx", ... },
  ...
]
```

In my bash script, I want to iterate through each object.

I've tried following, but it doesn't work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

output=$(myfile.js)
for row in $(echo ${output} | jq -c '.[]'); do
  echo $row
done
```

Comment: What do you want to archive while iterating each item? I'm sure most of it can be archived in one invocation `jq`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke `myfile.js` as a command. You need this:

```
output=$(cat myfile.js)
```

instead of this:

```
output=$(myfile.js)
```

But even then, your current approach isn't going to work well if the data has whitespace in it (which it does, based on the sample you posted). I suggest the following alternative:

```
jq -c '.[]' < myfile.js |
while read -r row
do
  echo "$row"
done
```

Output:

```
{"id":1,"name":"blah blah"}
{"id":2,"name":"xxx"}
```

**Edit:**
If your data is arising from a previous process invocation, such as `mongo` in your case, you can pipe it directly to `jq` (to remain portable), like this:

```
mongo myfile.js |
jq -c '.[]' |
while read -r row
do
  echo "$row"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote the post very confusing. The javascript file is executed in a mongo shell, so the that's why I stored the output in a variable. output = $(mongo myfile.js).

Comment: How can I make jq -c '.[]' < (mongo myfile.js) work?

Comment: You just need to pipe that output directly to `jq`, see updated example.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make jq -c '.[]' < (mongo myfile.js) work?

In a bash shell, you would write an expression along the following lines:

```
while read -r line ; do .... done < <(mongo myfile.js | jq -c .[])
```

Note that there are two occurrences of "<" in the above expression.

Also, the above assumes `mongo` is emitting valid JSON.  If it emits `//`-style comments, those would have somehow to be removed.

### Comparison with piping into `while`

If you use the idiom:

```
... | while read -r line ; do .... done
```

then the bindings of any variables in `....` will be lost.